# Converting HTML to PDF and attaching to email .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I am looking to use PDFSharp to convert a HTML page into a PDF. This then is attached into an email and sent all in one go.

So, I have a aspx page and vb code file in which gets called through a database SQL job.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ReqUrl As String, WorkflowID As String = String.Empty
    Using con As New SqlConnection(GlobalVariables.ConStr)
        Using com As New SqlCommand("EXEC App.GetWorkflowToSend", con)
            con.Open()
            Using dr = com.ExecuteReader
                Try
                    While dr.Read
                        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                        ReqUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + dr.Item("WorkflowLink")
                        WorkflowID = dr.Item("WorkflowID")
                        Dim r As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + dr.Item("WorkflowLink")
                        Dim p As String = Server.MapPath("~\Data\Files") + "\" + WorkflowID + ".pdf"
                        Dim t As Thread = New Thread(CType(
                                                 Function()
                                                     ConvertHTML(r, p)
                                                     SendMail(Nothing, EmailFrom, "email@address", "New PDF Generated " + WorkflowID, r + "<br/>" + p + "<br/>" + WorkflowID, EmailUser, EmailPass, EmailHost, EmailPort, EmailSSL, "", Nothing, p)
                                                 End Function, ThreadStart))
                        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
                        t.Start()
                        Response.Write(r + "<br>")
                        Response.Write(p)
                    End While
                Catch
                    SendMail(Nothing, EmailFrom, "email@address", "Error: " + Err.Description, WorkflowID, EmailUser, EmailPass, EmailHost, EmailPort, EmailSSL, "", Nothing)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

In the vb code I essentially call a database stored procedure. This returns some records.
For each of these records, I am currently using HttpContext.Current.Request.Url to make up a string which is essentially the the document url.
I also then declare and specify the location as a String of where I want the converted PDF to be stored.

```
Public Shared Function ConvertHTML(HTMLPage As String, FileName As String) As String
        Dim pngfilename As String = Path.GetTempFileName()
        Dim res As String = "" ' = ok
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        'Try

        Using wb As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser = New System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
            wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
            wb.Navigate(HTMLPage)
            While Not (wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While

            wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width
            wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height
            If wb.Height > 3000 Then
                wb.Height = 3000
            End If
            ' Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
            Dim b As Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height)
            Dim hr As Integer = b.HorizontalResolution
            Dim vr As Integer = b.VerticalResolution

            wb.DrawToBitmap(b, New Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height))
            wb.Dispose()
            If File.Exists(pngfilename) Then
                File.Delete(pngfilename)
            End If
            b.Save(pngfilename, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            b.Dispose()

            Using doc As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument = New PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument
                Dim page As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage = New PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage()
                page.Width = PdfSharp.Drawing.XUnit.FromInch(wb.Width / hr)
                page.Height = PdfSharp.Drawing.XUnit.FromInch(wb.Height / vr)
                doc.Pages.Add(page)

                Dim xgr As PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
                Dim img As PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage = PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromFile(pngfilename)
                xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0)
                doc.Save(FileName)
                doc.Close()
                img.Dispose()
                xgr.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
        Return res
    End Function
```

I run the conversion function with these two strings and finally call a mailing function.

[PDF Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1BO5.png)

The problem I am having at the moment is the attached PDF I receive in the email doesn't contain the correct output and states 'Navigation to the webpage was cancelled'.

```
http://127.0.0.1/PDF/TTR/4
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Prod\Data\Files\4.pdf
```

I also sent the two strings as output within the email and they look ok.

I'm sure there is something small missing whether that be in my conversion function or just in the main code file.

Comment: This is a badly constructed approach. You should start the "out of process" job and then just query for when job is done. and then bring the link - AJAX

Comment: Your issue is in the line 'Application.DoEvents()'. This method processes all messages and may execute code out of order. Using it is bad practice and you're better off learning about threading.